# Possible to forcibly uninstall Office 2010?

Tags: windows-xp, uninstall, microsoft-office-2010

I have been having great difficulties trying to uninstall **Microsoft Office Professional Plus 14.0.4734.1000**. I am trying to uninstall that version and install 14.0.4763.1000. That became necessary when I tried installing Service Pack 2 and 1 and neither worked, telling me that it could not find a valid install, and looking up that error showed me I had the wrong version installed to begin with.

Trying to install the correct one obviously fails, because one is already installed.

For some reason, it just does not want to cooperate. When I go to Add/Remove Programs in Control Panel and try to uninstall, I get **Uninstall did not complete successfully**.

I tried deleting registry keys left over from my 2007 install, [per this advice](https://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/office-2010-professional-plus-will-not-uninstall), but that did not help.

I've been through pretty much every option since. I next tried using the FixIt uninstaller. One of them did not even work, saying it was not a valid executable. The other started to run, but then says **The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed...**

Finally, I tried following the manual installation procedure according to Microsoft. I cannot even manually get rid of it! When I type in `Installer` in Run and try uninstalling an MSI, I get **The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed...**

I have done a separate search on this issue and my Windows Installer appears to be fine. Not sure why the error occurs. My registry ImagePath is set correctly and the file is in the proper folder. Furthermore, I've been able to install a number of other programs with no issues. Office (in particular, Office 2010) is the only problematic one.

Prior to having 14.0.4734, I had Office 2007 Enterprise installed and had no issues when I uninstalled that. I don't understand why I suddenly can't get rid of 2007.

Is there anything I can do short of nuking the computer? I would continue using 14.0.4734.1000 and call it a day, if it worked - and everything does *except* connecting Microsoft Exchange accounts in Outlook. If only I were able to do that, I would forget about this.

Comment: See if there is a restore point date the day of or prior to installing Office 2010, if so use system restore to remove it....https://neosmart.net/wiki/windows-system-restore/#Restore_Windows_XP

Comment: @Moab Surprisingly, I had some restore points even though I never explicitly enabled System Restore... trying this now. I'll have to reinstall everything I installed since uninstalling Office 2007, but I guess that beats reinstalling Windows.

Comment: @Moab That did it. It wasn't the answer I was looking for really, because it screwed up the rest of the OS in the process. But, it sounds like there wasn't much of a choice here. Thanks!

Comment: @Moab I guess that didn't do it. Microsoft Office Setup somehow detected it was still on the PC, even though it appeared to be gone! Tried installing the correct Office 2010, and it got all the way to the end and then said: "Microsoft Office... encountered an error during setup. Error 1714. Setup cannot remove the older version of Microsoft Office... Contact Microsoft Product Support Services for assistance."

Comment: @Moab If you other advice, I'd love to hear. Otherwise, I may try to wipe the computer. Didn't want it to come to this. No idea why Office 2010 is so poorly set up for this.